# Opengl, draw the depth texture to square

Tags: opengl, graphics, depth-buffer

This is how I set up my depth texture:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gbuffer_tex[2]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, int(screen_width), int(screen_height), 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gbuffer_tex[0], 0);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, gbuffer_tex[1], 0);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gbuffer_tex[2], 0);
```

Then I activate the framebuffer when I draw the scene onto it. And everything works fine.
If I run the program in gDebugger, the depth texture looks ok. But when I try to draw it, its just black. If I draw a texture that is set to a color attachment, it looks good.
Its just the depth texture that turns out black.

My fragment shader looks like this:

```
in VS_OUT { vec2 UV; } vs_in;
layout (binding = 3) uniform sampler2D depth_texture;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{
  vec2 tex_coord = vec2(vs_in.UV.x, -vs_in.UV.y); 
  float texture_color = texture(depth_texture, tex_coord).r;
  fragColor = vec4(texture_color, texture_color, texture_color, 1.0);
}
```

When I hover over the depth texture in gDebugger, the values are between 0.96 and 1.0. So it should be white not black.

Comment: Why are you using `COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE`? If you want to draw raw data, you should set compare mode to `NONE`, no?

Comment: More important than that, this actually will not do anything considering in the GLSL shader a plain old `sampler2D` is being used. You need to use `sampler2DShadow` if you want to enable depth comparison. If you want to see something other than black with your depth texture without doing anything complicated, I would suggest you square the sampled value.

Comment: I do not want to enable depth comparison, just draw the depth texture on a square. It does not matter if I square the values because all of them are zero. I have checked the values in the gdebugger, and all of them are zero.

Comment: Then *don't* use `COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE`. What do you think `COMPARE` suggests?